# How to restrict regular users from accessing admin page?

Tags: django

I would like to allow only admin users to access admin page and raise 404 error if user is not authenticated or is not a staff member. Is there a way to wrap admin view with another function to check if user is admin?

Edit:
Uhh, I should have pointed out first that by **admin** view I mean built-in django admin view. Any user can visit it and there they will see a login page for admins. I would like to override this behavior and raise 404 error, so that only admins are aware of this view. Also I have a login page for everyone, so there's no need for authorization in admin view

Comment: If you are using standard Django user model and standard Django admin then if user is no admin and he is not staff he cannot access admin page

Comment: Yes, user can't access admin functions but he still can type this in address bar: `http://example.com/admin` and he will see a login page for admins. I would like to override this behavior and raise 404 error, so that only admins are aware of this view. Also I have a login page for everyone, so there's no need for authorization in admin view

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your dispatch method on admin view like this:

```py
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

@method_decorator(user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_authenticated and u.is_staff))
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):  # noqa: D102
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

If you need this for multiple views, write mixin that overrides dispatch method.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how to link this code to admin view. I mean, the admin view that is built-in in django

Comment: Ah, I though you meant native django views. From what I know Django views are restricted to staff users and superusers, so I am not sure what you want really to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

so if you want easy solution just add to your main urls.py above admin urls:

```
path('admin/login/', view404), #asaing view that return 404
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but this not what I really wanted :)

Comment: why not? try it. i tested it myself. when you log in on your custom login page and you dont have is_admin and is_staff any attemt to go to /admin/... will end up with 404 or in my case 403, but if user is admin or staf it will work. of course if admin manually navigate to /admin/login/ he will get 404.